# Found a vulnerability, is there a bounty program?

Tags: support, security

I have found an exploit on all SE sites, that allows arbitrary code to be injected into the DOM. Where do I report this?

Answer (score 8):

The instructions for reporting vulnerabilities are available at https://stackexchange.com/about/security.

Thanks!